# Configure Lambda Function to a VPC in a Different Account? (Cross-Account)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have two accounts, account A and B. Account A has a VPC that contains resources. These resources are needed by my Lambda function in account B. I am trying to configure my lambda function to the VPC found in account A.

I tried a peering connection between the VPCs in account A and account B, which I created successfully. I then added routes to the route table for the peering connection. I then tried to connect the Lambda function in account B to the VPC in account A using this CLI command:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name <myLambdaName> --vpc-config SubnetIds=<subnet-in-vpc-account-A>,SecurityGroupIds=<sec-group-in-vpc-account-A>
```

However this failed with the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UpdateFunctionConfiguration operation: Error occurred while DescribeSecurityGroups. EC2 Error Code: InvalidGroup.NotFound. EC2 Error Message: The security group <sec-group-in-vpc-account-A> does not exist
```

Which suggests my VPCs are not connected, is it even possible for the lambda function to connect to a cross-account VPC?

Comment: The lambda function in account B has to be configured with the subnet and security group in account B, not A

Comment: You can check the RAM resource acce manager to share your subnet across account then try to deplpy the lambda in that subnet. Any specific reason you dont want to create 2 lambda's and do a cross account lambda call instead of sharing VPC